# Зачем * в аргументе функции namedtuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuple

Копаюсь под капотом у `namedtuple`. Обнаружил, что он принимает следующие аргументы:

```
def namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, rename=False, defaults=None, module=None):
```

Ко всем аргументам есть документация и вопросов особо не возникает, но есть вопрос по поводу звезды (3 аргумент)
Я изначально подумал, что это для защиты от передачи лишних аргументов (если по позиции передать больше, чем 2, то лишнее соберётся в лист-урну) или что-то такое

Но когда я попробовал вызвать

```
Car = namedtuple('Авто', "color age", 'Странный аргумент', rename=True)
```

Всё равно выдаёт ошибку о лишних аргументах

```
Car = namedtuple('Авто', "color age", 'Странный аргумент', rename=True)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: namedtuple() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

В связи с этим вопрос - зачем нужна эта звезда в аргументах функции?

Comment: `*` без имени - это ограничение использования параметров. Значит только первые 2 параметра (они же позиционные разрешены). Остальные параметры должны быть именованными

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Bare asterisk in function parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-parameters